# Whats the song that plays when Smith is having breakfast in 3-gatsu no lion episode 13

Tags: music, march-comes-in-like-a-lion

In *3-gatsu no Lion* episode 13, there's a song playing at the beginning of the episode when Smith is having breakfast.

What is that song?

Answer (score 0):

3 gatsu no Lion Original Soundtrack CD 3 - 7. Windmill

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Please include a video link to the song.